# How to configure Jenkins Plot Plugin with the dexcount-gradle-plugin?

Tags: android, jenkins

I'm trying to use the [Jenkins Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) to keep track of APK method counts using [dexcount-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin), but I can't figure out how to configure it.

Here's my configuration:

[image: jenkins_config]

Here's what I see:

[image: plot_output]

The data in my CSV file looks fine, and gets displayed in the Plot output above too.

The only thing I can think of is that I selected/changed some of the options after I had already run the job a couple of times (e.g. "Exclude zero as default Y-axis value"), so maybe the Plot part is in a bad state?  Do I need to clone this Jenkins job and start again?

The Console Output just says "Recording plot data" - I'm not sure if there is any way to get additional debug information...

**UPDATE**: This is depressing, but after my build slave and the Jenkins master were rebooted, my earlier plot points appeared:

[image: earlier_plots_working]

Initially I suspected that Jenkins needed to be restarted after the plugin was installed, but my Jenkins administrator may have forgotten to do it.  *However*, my new plots since the reboot are also not appearing, so something is still wrong...

Comment: How about creating a new dummy job and using your csv file and plot plugin. Change the csv data in each run and see if your graphs show something useful.

Comment: Did you pointed out, what was wrong ? I've the same behaviour